# Python Defining Business days and working hours

Tags: python-3.x, business-rules

I am looking for guidance on how to create a variable (Business_Time) which contains only business days (not weekends) and where i can set working hours (9am - 6pm GMT).

The reason for this is because i'm trying to calculate some SLA's (how long employees have to complete a task), however if the end time falls outside of these business days/hours, then i can set it to a specific time.

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` already implement [`BusinessHour`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessHour.html) and [`BusinessDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay.html):

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BusinessDay
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BusinessHour
from dateutil import parser

myDate = parser.parse('Fri, 7 Jan 2022 17:00:00 +0000 (UTC)')
myWorkTime = BusinessDay(1) + BusinessHour(1)

print(myDate + myWorkTime)
```

This will print `Timestamp('2022-01-11 10:00:00+0000', tz='tzutc()')`.

You can find a lot of tutorials over the internet (like [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-tseries-offsets-businessday/?ref=lbp) for example)